# Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}=(1,t,t^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$T(f(t))=\int_0^2f(t)dt$ from $P_2$ to $P_2$

I was thinking we could evaluate the integral and get

$$\frac{(f(2))^2-(f(0))^2}{2}$$

But I'm not sure how to evaluate the integral under the given basis.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T:P_2\to P_2$ be the map $T(f(t))=\int_0^2 f(t)\,dt$. For $0\leq k\leq 2$ let $e_k(t)=t^k$ and note that $\beta=\{e_0,e_1,e_2\}$ is a basis of $P_2$.

To compute the entries of $[A]_\beta$, note that
\begin{array}{lcrcrcr}
T(e_0) & = & \color{red}{2}\ e_0 & + & \color{red}{0}\ e_1 & + & \color{red}{0}\ e_2  \\
T(e_1) & = & \color{blue}{2}\ e_0 & + & \color{blue}{0}\ e_1 & + & \color{blue}{0}\ e_2 \\
T(e_2) & = & \color{green}{\frac{8}{3}}\ e_0 & + & \color{green}{0}\ e_1 & + & \color{green}{0}\ e_2 
\end{array}
(Check these computations yourself!)
This implies
$$
[A]_\beta
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{2}  &   \color{blue}{2} &   \color{green}{\frac{8}{3}}    \\
\color{red}{0}  &   \color{blue}{0} &   \color{green}{0}    \\
\color{red}{0}  &   \color{blue}{0} &   \color{green}{0}       
\end{bmatrix}
$$